# Search array struct in an array in the struct

Tags: swift

help me find an array in the array. In this implementation, I return the entire array.

```
[(name: "Bell 2", arr: [arrSub(sub_txt: "Test 2, 1"),arrSub(sub_txt: "Test 2, 2")])]
```

I need to return:

```
[(name: "Bell 2", arr: [arrSub(sub_txt: "Test 2, 2")])]
```

**// Playground**

```
import UIKit

struct arrSub {
    let sub_txt: String
}

struct test {
    let name: String
    let arr: [arrSub]

    init(name: String, arr: [arrSub]) {
        self.name = name
        self.arr  = arr
    }
}

var testArr = [test]()

testArr.append(test(name: "Line 1", arr: [arrSub(sub_txt: "Line 1, 1"), arrSub(sub_txt: "Line 1, 2")]))
testArr.append(test(name: "Bell 2", arr: [arrSub(sub_txt: "Bell 2, 1"), arrSub(sub_txt: "Bell 2, 2")]))
testArr.append(test(name: "Bell 2", arr: [arrSub(sub_txt: "Test 2, 1"), arrSub(sub_txt: "Test 2, 2")]))

let new = testArr.filter({
    $0.arr.contains(where: { $0.sub_txt.contains("Test 2, 2") } )        
})

print(new)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `filter` won't help you achieve your goals, since you are trying to modify the `test` instances as well by filtering their `arr` property. You can use `compactMap` instead of `filter` to return modified `test` instances in case they fulfilled the `filter` criterion or `nil` if they didn't and `compactMap` will only keep the non-nil values.

```
let new = testArr.compactMap({ test->Test? in
let foundArrSub = test.arr.filter({ $0.sub_txt.contains("Test 2, 2") })
    if foundArrSub.count > 0 {
        return Test(name: test.name, arr: foundArrSub)
    }
    return nil
})
```

Test data:

```
var testArr = [Test]()

testArr.append(Test(name: "Line 1", arr: [ArrSub(sub_txt: "Line 1, 1"), ArrSub(sub_txt: "Line 1, 2")]))
testArr.append(Test(name: "Bell 2", arr: [ArrSub(sub_txt: "Bell 2, 1"), ArrSub(sub_txt: "Bell 2, 2")]))
testArr.append(Test(name: "Bell 2", arr: [ArrSub(sub_txt: "Test 2, 1"), ArrSub(sub_txt: "Test 2, 2"),ArrSub(sub_txt: "Test 2, 23")]))
```

> [__lldb_expr_1.Test(name: "Bell 2", arr: [__lldb_expr_1.ArrSub(sub_txt: "Test 2, 2"), __lldb_expr_1.ArrSub(sub_txt: "Test 2, 23")])]

You should conform to the Swift naming convention, which is UpperCamelCase for types, so I changed `test` to `Test` and `arrSub` to `ArrSub`.

Comment: This search will find only one record always in the substructure. But I need to return all the elements that are equal to the search condition.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Dávid Pásztor. I just slightly corrected

```
let new = testArr.compactMap { (myTest) -> test? in
if let foundArrSub = myTest.arr.first(where: { $0.sub_txt.contains("Test 2, 2") }){
    return test(name: myTest.name, arr: [foundArrSub])
}
return nil}
```

This search will find only one record always in the substructure. But I need to return all the elements that are equal to the search condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` also

```
let news =  testArr.reduce([test]()) { (result, testObj) -> [test] in

            let internalArray  = testObj.arr.filter({ (arraySub) -> Bool in
                return   arraySub.sub_txt.range(of:"Test 2, 2") != nil
            }).filter({ (arraySub) -> Bool in
                return   arraySub.sub_txt.range(of:"Test 2, 2") != nil
            })
        if internalArray.count > 0 {
            return result + [test.init(name: testObj.name, arr: internalArray)]
        }else{
            return result
        }
    }

    print(news)
```